# ASP.NET C#: Write to HttpResponse or StringBuilder Interchangeably

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, httpresponse, stringbuilder

I have a ASP.NET C# method (Let's call it writeData.) that repeatedly writes strings to the Response with Response.Write.  A few days ago, a different scenario required that I save the resultant data to a string instead of writing it.  So I had to duplicate the entire function while using a StringBuilder instead.  Is there a way I could design writeData so that it could write to a HttpResponse or a StringBuilder interchangeably, possibly as an argument?  In the below examples, I have insterted a for loop which will loop 10,000 times, but my code likely loops even more than that.  So it's important that I make every loop as fast as possible.

```
//Response.Write Method
private void writeData()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        Response.Write("Text.");
    }
}

//StringBuilder.Append Method
private string writeData()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        sb.Append("Text.");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Here are my two candidates to fix the problem:

```
//Candidate 1
private string writeData(object responseOrStringBuilder)
{
    HttpResponse response = responseOrStringBuilder as HttpResponse;
    StringBuilder sb = responseOrStringBuilder as StringBuilder;
    bool useResponse = response != null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        if (useResponse) { response.Write("Text."); }
        else { sb.Append("Text."); }
    }
    return useResponse ? null : sb.ToString();
}

//Candidate 2
public void writeData(Action<string> writer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        writer("Test.");
    }
}
public void writeDataResponse()
{
    writeData((string text) => { Response.Write(text); });
}
public string writeDataStringBuilder()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    writeData((string text) => { sb.Append(text); });
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

My "Candidate 1" has drawbacks, including having to attempt to cast an HttpResponse and a StringBuilder.  It also has to repeatedly check the value of the useResponse variable.  These problems become even more exaggerated since writeData itself could even be called in a loop.

"Candidate 2" might work better, but I don't know how efficient it is to pass the Action argument as I have done.  I've also used lambda notation, and there might be a more efficient way to write that too.  I may try to test these later today.

I would appreciate your ideas.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after I posted this question, I decided to do a performance test myself for my particular situation.  "Candidate 2" was the clear winner.  The speed of both seemed roughly the same.  I had expected "Candidate 1" to be slower.  But "Candidate 2" was much easier to read.  I'd love to get other suggestions, but given the amount of activity here, I don't suspect that's going to happen.